# AngularJS: Binding to an array, but a specific property?

Tags: angularjs

I'm using this directive ([wallop-slider-angularjs](https://github.com/andyshora/wallop-slider-angularjs)) and it requires an array of image urls, but my urls are properties of an array of objects.  How can I bind the property in such a way that it is acceptable to the directive?

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users">

    <wallop-slider
        data-images="??user.media.mediumURL??"
        data-animation="rotate"
        data-current-item-index="currentSliderIndex"></wallop-slider>

</div>


media = [{'mediumURL':'http://whatever.com/image.jpg'},{'mediumURL':'http://whatever.com/image2.jpg'}]
```

Comment: Can't you just loop through your original array and extract the urls from that, passing the 'filtered' array to the directive?

Comment: @MohammadSepahvand - There's only one problem with that... this is already inside of an ng-repeat... Updating the code to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this with a custom filter:

```
app.filter('extractProperty', function() { 
   return function(array, propertyName) {
    return array.map(function(item) { return item[propertyName]; });
   };
});
```

To get an array containing the specific property you must use it like that:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users">
 <wallop-slider data-images="{{ media | extractProperty:'mediumURL' }}"...></wallop-slider>
</div>
```

Here is a working example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/WpuOCU?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Just create a function on the scope which will extract the needed properties from the array. Something like:

```
scope.getMediumUrls = function(arr) {
  return $.map(arr, function(item) { return item.mediumURL; });
}
```

And then use it on the directive:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users">
  <wallop-slider data-images="getMediumUrls(user.media)"...></wallop-slider>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: If you already have a dependency on jQuery, I would pick [Shay Friedmans answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22344482/248055).

I think this will do your trick (without the need for any additional libraries).

```
// Helper function to pluck the url property from the media items.

function pluckUrls() {
  var ret = [], c = $scope.mediaItems.length;

  while(c--) {
    ret.push($scope.mediaItems[c].url);
  }

  return ret;  
}

// Function that is called each watch cycle. The return value will differ
// if one of the urls has been modified.

function getUniqueWatchValue() {
  return pluckUrls().join();
}

// Function that is called whenever one of the urls has been modified.

function watchValueChanged() {
  console.log('One of the urls has been modified');
  $scope.mediaUrls = pluckUrls();
}

// Hook up the watch.

$scope.$watch(getUniqueWatchValue, watchValueChanged);
```

Plunker in action can be found [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y9wxZs?p=preview).

Note: I noticed a piece of code in that wallop-slider thingy that is watching a reference to the array, not it contents. I haven't tested it but it probably requires you to recreate the array completely instead of simply adding or removing element from it.

```
$scope.$watch('images', function(images) {
  if (images.length) {
    _goTo(0);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the object along with the key and corresponding properties.

Suppose you have JS object as

```
var media = [
 {'mediumURL':'http://whatever.com/image.jpg'},
 {'mediumURL':'http://whatever.com/image2.jpg'}
];
```

Lets apply for in loop for getting values

```
for(key in media){
 alert(media[key].mediumURL);
}
```

Here "key" refers to index for media[] and "mediumURL" is the individual corresponding property.

In your case,

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users">

    <wallop-slider
        data-images="??user.mediumURL??"
        data-animation="rotate"
        data-current-item-index="currentSliderIndex"></wallop-slider>

</div>
```

**Note:** You were using "user.media.mediumURL", hence it wont work because "media" is not property for each object structure under media[].

You can refer to [this link](http://justinklemm.com/angularjs-filter-ordering-objects-ngrepeat/) for more details on ng-repeat looping examples.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do is using underscore like the following:

```
    <wallop-slider
        data-images="_.pluck(user.media.mediumURL, 'mediumURL')"
        data-animation="rotate"
        data-current-item-index="currentSliderIndex"></wallop-slider>

</div>
```

But before that you need do 2 things:

1. add underscore

   `<script src="/whatever/underscore.js"></script>`
2. inject underscorejs into controller like the folloiwng

`angular.module('app', [])
      .controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $window) {
        $scope._ = $window._
    });`

Hope that help,
Ron